# Blender IK doesn't bend knee

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

https://youtu.be/5HBzaBwuUoA
In my rig, I have the IK constraint between the shin, the heel, and the knee, but the leg doesn't bend the way I want it to, any help?

Comment: do you have a pole bone

Comment: Yes, I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY tutorial, but my issue stands, the IK works when there is no pole bone, but obviously the knee bends the wrong way.

Comment: you may need to bend it a bit in Edit mode, if it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Its as Moonboots says, you need to slightly bend the bones forwards before you use IK constraints